# Increasing the number of instances for RESTful CXF service

Tags: cxf

Is there a way to increase the number of Restful CXF service instance?  This is required in order to increase the performance of my service in the event when multiple users are trying to access my app at the same time.

EDIT:

How this annotation affects the creation of service instances.

@FactoryType(value = FactoryType.Type.Pooled, args = { "25" })

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Deploy multiple times and put a load balancer in front. (Of course, you also have to ensure that there is a consistent model that the instances all access, probably through a shared database, and that will probably become a bottleneck…)